# Licensing an application which uses both CC-BY-SA 3.0 and AGPLv3 content

Tags: agpl-3.0, cc-by-sa

I'm planning on releasing a web application which relies on two open source dictionaries. The first one is released under CC-BY-SA 3.0 (Wiktionary) and the second one is released under AGPLv3.
The dictionaries are bundled together with the application (but each in a dedicated source directory, if it matters). In each directory I've included the original license.

What are my options when choosing a license for my application?

Can I release it under AGPLv3 based on compatibility with CC-BY-SA 3.0 (CC-BY-SA 3.0 -> CC-BY-SA 4.0 -> GPLv3 -> AGPLv3)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should work.

The CC-BY-SA is rather simple compared to software licenses as it does not require any source distribution. So any license which allows usage under conditions to give credits and ensure that freedoms for distribution and adoption are retained should be fine. For CC-BY-SA and GPLv3 their respective stewards [agreed](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility:_GPLv3) that they are compatible.

This said: you can well license your code under one (e.g. AGPL), and keep the dictionaries under their respective licenses. You only have to indicate the licenses and copyright-and comply with the AGPL overall.

All this said:IANAL